# Storing binaries in database: do I miss some drawbacks in this particular situation?

Tags: mysql, database, blob

I know this theme has been widely discussed in the past, and I thoroughly analysed the many insightful answers on the matter - confirming my idea that, *generally*, storing blobs in the db is bad practice.

Now let's take a look at the following scenarios:

- There's `users`, which has a one-to-many relationship with `images`;
- The `images` rows would contain, apart from `users`' FK and some metadata (date, title...), the following binaries (or file paths pointing to the following binaries):

  - Thumbnail (a ridiculously small binary);
  - Fullsize (will actually be preprocessed, to be about 400x600 and around 35-45kb;
- I will never need any data from the `images` table without an image as well (and anyway, I know where not to use `SELECT *`);
- I want to use fs and memory cache;
- In the most common scenario, I'll just need the thumbs (only getting the fullsize images dynamically on some events and, in those cases, getting them by ID). Clarifying: either many very very small pictures or one still pretty small one per call;
- Users will want to change their pictures' data, delete them, change them *a lot*.

Everything seems to make me think that the DB solution is optimal.

Are there drawbacks I fail to see (apart from the obvious open db connection in the event of no cache)?

Comment: Does "fs and memory cache" mean "file system and memory cache"?

Comment: Most definitely (eleven chars).

Answer (score 0):

One problem in this scenario is making backups, or syncing a "development" or "test" environment with the production one (moving around a db dump would be painful). It's also much more simpler to edit *en masse* all the images, if they are on fs (say: mass create a new size for the images).

Anyway, I don't fully get into the real advantages of this approach versus a "pointers in db, files on fs" one. The memory cache, perhaps? These days when I think about blobs, I think of S3 anyway :)

Comment: Well, the obvious advantage would be not having to track both the fs and the db. 

Also, I never move all my data from the test db to the production one so I can't see that as a problem.

Comment: Given that this not obvious at all (in my experience), I wonder which are the other advantageS. If this is the only _perceived_ one, you shlould rethink about it.

Comment: Having to update two things instead of one is the most obvious disadvantage I can think of. Then there's versioning, rollbacks, warranty of data integrity and metadata sync...