# Store avatars in a  mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, image-uploading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Is uploading a picture and storing it in the database a good way to keep track of avatars
Or is there a better solution when people are uploading a picture.

working with jquery php and mysql

**I don't have experience in this so how would I go about it?**

thinadv, Richard

Comment: This question is extremely open ended.  You should probably try some things experiment and then come back with a more specific question

Comment: Generally, store the file in the file system, and store its path/URL in the database. You usually don't want the actual files in the DB.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237451/storing-binaries-in-database-do-i-miss-some-drawbacks-in-this-particular-situati/

Comment: This is a DUP of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay.

Comment: yes, this is a lazy question. I acknowledge that I could have searched before I posted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store files in the db you would use a BLOB, they have their up's and downs.  Otherwise you would store a path and populate the src attribute of the image tag with the path from the db.

Comment: thanks Austinbv I think I will try to store the path, that seems the most logical. I have a problem with being to generic today.